# Dynamically change image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have set of tabs with text and icons. The active tabs have a white background with blue text and icons. The other tabs are the opposite. What I want to do is simply dynamically change the icons when they are active. The blue icon works, but doesn't change to white when not active.

Here's what I have:

```
if ($('#project_details').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#tab1').attr('src','img/blue.png');
} else {
    $('#tab1').attr('src','img/white.png');
}
```

HTML:

```
<li id="project_details" class="active">
<img src="" id="tab1">Project Details</li>
```

Comment: Code looks fine, I'm just wondering what event triggers your code to execute?

Comment: You'll need to either 1) use CSS and background images instead, which doesn't rely on events, or 2) share what mechanism you're using for the tabs so we can help construct an event callback.

Comment: I am using the bootstrap jquery for tabs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `active` class is already added and removed from the element automatically by the browser, this is because it's a css pseudo-class. Your code to change the src attribute looks fine, but I don't see anything which would trigger your code to run. (Note: this is a response to previous answers telling OP to add/remove `active` manually.)

When exactly do you want this if statement to execute? When a user clicks on another tab? If so, I would use jQuery to create an event handler for the click event of a tab.

Comment: i tried an `.on('click')` but it didn't work. is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Indeed, I would reccomend you identify a common element which groups your tabs, such as the parent `ul` element. You can create a selector such as $('ul li').on('click', function(e){ //code }); So any click on a `li` inside your `ul` will trigger a block of code.